# How to prevent second audio track volume from increasing/decreasing automatically because of other audio track?

Tags: imovie

I'm using iMovie (10.1.14) to make a demo video.  I recorded the video and I added voice parts here and there.

Then I added the music as an additional audio track.

The problem is, in the parts when I'm speaking, the music track automatically lowers the volume then goes back up when my speaking stops.

Here's a screenshot showing how the volume of the audio track goes up when there's a break in the speaking:

[image]

It appears to be trying to mix the audio for me, but I want the music to be at consistent volume through the whole video.

Is there any way to fix the music track volume level so it doesn't automatically go up and down?

Comment: I don't use iMovie myself, but the term you're looking for is 'ducking'. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124302/ducking-in-imovie-10